# How to pass command line arguments to InstallShield debugger?

Tags: debugging, installshield

When running the InstallShield X debugger I can't find a way to tell it to run silently in order to debug a silent install.

The debugger seems to run the equivalent of a "setup.exe" command line which displays the GUI, but I want "setup.exe /s" which takes input from setup.iss.

Is there a way to specify command line parameters for debugging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to start the InstallScript debugger. You can start it from the InstallShield IDE, which is what I expect you're doing. Or you can start it from the command line of your setup with `/d`. Mix the `/s` and `/d` together, and you should be able to debug the silent case. Or if this is an InstallScript MSI, you may also want to set certain MSI properties to enable debugging of custom actions.

See [Setup.exe and Update.exe Command-Line Parameters](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield15helplib/IHelpSetup_EXECmdLine.htm#wp1039960) for details, looking at the Debugging section which describes both `/d` and `/v"ISSCRIPTDEBUG=1 ISSCRIPTDEBUGPATH=\"path-to-Setup.dbg\""`